# asp.net textbox selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a standard asp:textbox which is editable and I want to be able to select a portion of text, click a button, and then encapsulate the selected text with html tags.

For example the textbox has this text:

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

If I select "The quick brown fox" and click a button I want the text to become `<i>The quick brown fox</i>`

How to detect the selected text? With winforms you can use richtextbox but no such thing in standard asp.net controls. And it also MUST be an asp:texbox control.

Comment: Why are you so certain about "must be asp:textbox"? I think that it's impossible.

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be I guess but it is part of the edit template of a gridview and not sure anything will work right in its place

Comment: Then search for some html rich text editors or try use contentEditable attribute for div.

Comment: I cannot bind to div unfortunately, only eval works, I get this error: A call to Bind must be assigned to a property of a control inside a template. I need to bind because I need the text from the div to be send to the DB

Comment: Minor nitpick: you should really surround with `<em>`, not `<i>` =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rarely recommend this, because the controls are kind of clunky, but you could use the [ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/) for this.  Just follow the instructions on the website to install the toolkit, and include the DLL in your project.

The toolkit has an extender that you can apply to a normal `<asp:TextBox>` called [`HTMLEditorExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx).  See the samples on the linked page for the functionality.  Basically, all you have to do is point the `HTMLEditorExtender` markup at an existing `TextBox` control.

Here's a simplified version from the sample on that page:

```
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" 
    TargetControlID="yourTextBoxID" DisplaySourceTab="true" 
    runat="server"/>
    <Toolbar> 
        <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
        <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
        <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
        <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
        <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
        <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
        <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
        <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
        <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
    </Toolbar>
</ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Note that you need to set "yourTextBoxID" in `TargetControlID="yourTextBoxID"` to the ID of the TextBox control you want the extender to apply to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CKEditor as advanced html editor instead of textarea. http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a very good rich textbox editor. http://www.telerik.com/developer-productivity-tools.aspx